# How to list files installed by a snap package?

Tags: snap

After a snap has been installed with `sudo snap install [package]` how can I list the files which have been installed by the snap?

Answer (score 49, accepted):

Snaps are compressed squashfs files, which typically get 'installed' to `/var/lib/snapd/snaps`. So if you `snap install ohmygiraffe` you'll find a file called `/var/lib/snapd/snaps/ohmygiraffe_3.snap`.

If you'd never installed a snap before then you'll also have a `core` snap which lives at the same location.

If you're interested in seeing what's inside that snap, look in `/snap/<snapname>/<current>/`. Note that you're peering into the snap, the contents aren't unpacked onto your filesystem.

The only other thing you'll find is a `.desktop` file in `/var/lib/snapd/desktop/applications`.

Once your snap has been run, you may also find data in `~/snap/<snapname>`.

Answer (score 16):

Snaps are standalone squashfs images, which means listing what they install is as simple as listing the contents of the image. These images get mounted into place at `/snap/<snapname>/<snap revision>`, although you can just use `/snap/<snapname>/current` for the currently-active revision, e.g.:

```
$ ls -lR /snap/<snapname>/current/
```

Answer (score 2):

If you don't have root and/or want to look at a package that isn't installed and so isn't in `/var/lib/snapd/snaps`, you can use

```
cd /some/dir/for/storing/snaps/
mkdir snapname
cd snapname/
snap download snapname
unsquashfs -l *.snap
```

where `snapname` is the name of some snap.

unsquashfs may be installed with  `sudo apt install squashfs-tools`

Comment: Replacing snapname by feh-lreenaers I get `cannot download snap "feh-lreenaers": no snap revision available as specified` ; using feh-lreenaers_1 instead I get `internal error: unsupported download with instance name "feh-lreenaers_1"`

Comment: `snap info` indicates there is no stable version as I write this. Try the --candidate flag (or whatever other version you want to try). See `snap help download`