# Cannot change lock screen background on Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: gnome, 18.04, lock-screen

Before you mark the question as a duplicate, I read all of the posts regarding this, but nothing helped me. I'd like to change the background picture of the lock screen.

I changed the `ubuntu.css` and `gdm3.css` accordingly to

```
#lockDialogGroup {
  background: #000000 url(file:///usr/share/wallpapers/minimalistic-gray_00323985.jpg);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center;
}
```

Which results in a change of the Background of the **log in** screen, not the lock screen. When I press `super + L` the screen containing time has the correct background. When I swipe it up to tipe in my password, the purple Ubuntu screen still appears. If I click to change the user, the log in screen appears with the right background. I have the same background picture enabled in `gnome tweaks` for desktop background and lock screen.

I'm running Ubuntu 18.04 GNOME on a TuXedo Laptop. And I use `Communitheme` - maybe thats the problem?

Any ideas why it doesn't work? (I rebooted multiple times, so that's not the problem.)

EDIT: The output of `sudo nano /usr/share/gnome-shell/modes/ubuntu.json` is

```
{
    "parentMode": "user",
    "stylesheetName": "ubuntu.css",
    "enabledExtensions": ["ubuntu-dock@ubuntu.com", "ubuntu-appindicators@ubuntu.com"]
}
```

Comment: @PRATAP Exactly, thats the picture I want to use. Hm, I can change the appearance of the background and lock screen both in settings and gnome-tweaks. I'm not a 100 percent sure, how it's called on your system since mine is in german, but it should be something like `Appearance` in gnome-tweaks.

Comment: I bought it last week, so I assume it's a fresh install. I changed the file, but unfortunately it changes nothing. Maybe it's because I use `Communitheme`? Or maybe, because it says I don't have the extension installed to change the `Shell` theme?

Comment: @PRATAP See the updated question above.

Comment: while i was trying to solve similar question.. i got a clue why it didn't work.. can you please let me know how did you instaall that Communitheme.. snap install or PPA and APT install?

Comment: I'm sorry I haven't replied yet, but messing with this "Do not edit by hand"-file made some problems. I installed the Communitheme with snap. What does that mean?

Comment: snap and apt are two different things.. you can get differences easily by googling.. you can check by opening snap file in the below answer and see the color which is showing at lock screen..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**If it's a PPA install**

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:communitheme/ppa
sudo apt update
sudo apt install ubuntu-communitheme-session
```

then this is the file

```
/usr/share/gnome-shell/theme/communitheme/gnome-shell.css
```

**When it's a snap install**

```
sudo snap install communitheme
```

this is the file

```
/snap/communitheme/1593/share/gnome-shell/theme/Communitheme/gnome-shell.css
```

but this snap file is Read-Only.. read about why this snap file cant be saved like other files. https://askubuntu.com/a/1035241/739431..

short .gif file for APT installed Communitheme unlock-screen change...
https://i.stack.imgur.com/ohz0H.jpg

Comment: I did, but it didn't fix the problem. There is no difference in just renaming the file, is there? Why should renaming fix the problem? Thanks for the suggestions anyways. Do you have any more ideas left?

Comment: Of course not. I followed your instructions thoroughly. But I don't really see a difference between creating a new file and copy-pasting the content, and just renaming `ubuntu.css` and change the name within the `.json` file. But my knowledge is limited.

Comment: I did exactly what you proposed to, but it had no effect.

Comment: Yes, the folder `wallpapers` exists in that exact directory. Elsewise, changing `ubuntu.css` wouldn't have had any effect on my login screen, but it had. I tried the black color with no effect. Seems like changing the `json` file, isn't the only thing one has to change.

Comment: But every time I try to change the content of the `json` file I get this warning `(gedit:3917): WARNING **: 08:58:51.596: Set document metadata failed:`

Comment: It still has lock.css

Comment: What do we do if we want to change the CSS values of a communitheme snap? I know it's a compressed disk image, are there easy workarounds or config tools, or will I need to uncompress the snap, edit it and recompress it, and do that every time the communitheme snap updates?

Comment: @PRATAP I'd like to change the non-editable CSS files of the communitheme snap.

Answer (score 0):

Just use this Extension to change the lock screen Wallpaper

Link: https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/1476/unlock-dialog-background/

install it and change it to any lock screen image

Working on Pop OS 20.10