# Writing a file to a read-only filesystem

Tags: permissions, mount, filesystem

What I want to do is to replace the background music file (`bgm.ogg`) in the `.config` folder of RetroArch with a custom one.

The issue is, I can't write any files in the directory that `bgm.ogg` is in; having installed RetroArch using snap, the filepath for me is `/snap/retroarch/1396/.config/assets/sounds/bgm.ogg`.

The errors I receive all mention that I'm trying to write to a read-only filesystem (details below). From what I've checked, the read-only filesystem is the `/1396/` folder; meaning I don't get these errors in the `/retroarch/` folder or higher.

Is there a way I can write a file in the subfolders of `/1396/`?

Also, why is `/1396/` a filesystem?

---

Here is the error I get when trying to copy a new `bgm.ogg` file:

```
$cp /path/to/new/bgm.ogg /snap/retroarch/1396/.config/assets/sounds/

cp: cannot create regular file '/snap/retroarch/1396/.config/assets/sounds/bgm.ogg: Read-only file system
```

---

Here is the message when trying to change the permissions of the `/1396/` folder (filesystem), nothing changes after this:

```
$chmod 777 1396

chmod: changing permissions of '1396/': Read-only file system
```

---

Here is another attempt of remounting `/1396/` as a read-write filesystem:

```
$sudo mount -o remount,rw '/snap/retroarch/1396/'

mount: /snap/retroarch/1396: cannot remount /dev/loop36 read-write, is write-protected.
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Cannot modify files installed by \`snap\`](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1035127/cannot-modify-files-installed-by-snap). Essentially the answer is "No". You can't modify snaps because they use a read-only file system and you can't write to a read-only file system

Comment: Thanks, yes it did answer my question. I've updated the post.

Comment: The RO file-system is intended prevent what you're trying to do. If you want to change what's in a RO package, you modify the source & re-create the package.