# Unable to copy/paste in certain registries

Tags: permissions, nautilus

I'm trying to copy paste a file in `/snap/notshowingthisforprivacy/1234/usr/lib` and can't paste anything. This registry is under "other locations" and not my desktop or `./home`, I have the admin-nautilus mod, and when opening the registry in admin mode the same issue persists. Opening the registry in admin mode leads to the paste option being grayed out, when trying to do Ctrl+V I get a warning that I don't have permission and I'm not asked for an admin password.

I cannot edit permissions of the folder because I don't have permission, but again I am not even given the option to enter my admin password. How do I force enable this registry to have the same options as `./home`?

Options grayed out image:

[image: Options grayed out image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Cannot modify files installed by \`snap\`](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1035127/cannot-modify-files-installed-by-snap)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Unable to modify files in root even after booting it up as admin](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1487621/unable-to-modify-files-in-root-even-after-booting-it-up-as-admin)