# Unable to modify files in root even after booting it up as admin

Tags: permissions, nautilus, sudo, lvm, read-only

I'm trying to copy+paste a plugin for OBS under `/snap/obs-studio/1284/usr/lib`. It's located in root. The paste option is grayed out doing:

```
sudo su
nautilus
```

leads to me opening it as `admin:///snap/obs-studio/1284/usr/lib` however the option is STILL grayed out. Trying Ctrl+V leads to this error message.

[image: error message]

I've tried to go into the permissions of the folder and then under properties to change the permissions, however I get this error message.

[image: error message]

When I was installing Ubuntu I used LVM for file management, I had and still have no idea what this means. When I was installing it I googled and some people said it's a nice feature; I have no idea if this is connected to this issue. I just thought I should bring it up. I've found some people discussing the same issue, but for most people it seems like doing `sudo su nautilus` or `gksudo nautilus` fixes it, however as said this didn't work for me.

EDIT: I need to modify a root file because it's where the OBS plugins are locaited,someone suggested that they're in

```
~/snap/obs-studio/current/.config/obs-studio/plugins
```

However the /current folder is just empty for me, shown here: [image: here]

Have I installed OBS wrong? I've just installed through Ubuntu Software thingy. Is there something i need to do in OBS? Also trying to automatically find the plugin folder through OBS's "File->Show Settings folder" doesn't do anything.
Because someone asked: I need to paste this plugin to be able to record per-application audio. Application audio capture is only a thing for windows. I need to have the game audio and discord audio as separate tracks to be able to edit out certain clips of discord/game audio, in case someone swears or the game is too loud for a short time.

Comment: I don't know much about snaps, but my limited understanding is that they are read-only. Please [edit] your question and explain _why_ you want to do this. What is the actual problem that you are trying to solve by pasting this plugin.

Comment: As an aside, you never need `sudo su`, much less `sudo su command`. Just use `sudo -i` to get a root shell and `sudo command` to run a command as root.

Answer (score 6):

Those application directories under `/snap` are mount points for read only loop devices created by `snapd` and you can't modify them nor you need to ... Those are separate filesystems for a special purpose and not your usual kind of directories ... i.e. :

```
$ findmnt -T /snap/obs-studio/current
TARGET                SOURCE      FSTYPE   OPTIONS
/snap/obs-studio/1284 /dev/loop52 squashfs ro,nodev,relatime,errors=continue,threads=single
```

... those are part of the sandboxing/isolation mechanism of SNAP … their read-only state and their default permissions are part of that process as well and if you break them, those applications will break … you have no business there at all and even if you manage to somehow vandalize (*by modifying*) them, then they  will be damaged and will stop working ... So, stay away from them.

However, their respective user specific configuration directions can be usually found under `~/snap` (*`~` is your home directory*) … For example, the plugins directory for the SNAP version of OBS-Studio on Ubuntu should be at:

```
~/snap/obs-studio/current/.config/obs-studio/plugins
```

... and that is where your plugins should go.

Comment: There is no `~/snap/obs-studio/current/.config/obs-studio/plugins` ? the /current folder is empty?  Trying to manually access the folder in which plugins are located thru OBS (using the File-> show settings folder) doesn't do anything?? Have i installed OBS wrong? I've installed OBS simply via the Ubuntu software thingy.
I Would post an image but can't under replys...

Comment: Edited the original post with this same info + picture.

Comment: @Xyozni `.config` is a hidden directory … Press Ctrl+h in the file manager to show hidden directories/files.

Comment: Ohhhh... Thanks mate, i see the folder now, copy+paste works.