# mount and read-only issue on Ubuntu 22.04

Tags: mount, 22.04, chmod, read-only, chown

Can anyone please tell me how to resolve this problem? The file system says it is read-only when I try to use `chown` or `chmod`.

> Apc Extension failed: Error: EROFS: read-only file system, rename '/snap/code/155/usr/share/code/resources/app/out/bootstrap-amd.js' -> '/snap/code/155/usr/share/code/resources/app/out/bootstrap-amd.js.apc.extension.backup'

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Cannot modify files installed by \`snap\`](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1035127/cannot-modify-files-installed-by-snap)