# How to uninstall dotnet from Ubuntu 20.10 completely?

Tags: uninstall, 20.10, software-uninstall, installed-programs

I have installed dotnet on my Ubuntu 20.10 but for some reason I want to remove it but I don't know how to do it please help.

[image]

Answer (score 16):

Try with major and minor version only:

```
sudo apt remove --purge dotnet-sdk-6.0
sudo apt remove --purge dotnet-runtime-6.0
```

Comment: This worked for me! `sudo apt purge dotnet-sdk-6.0`

Comment: before and after remove you can list: `dotnet --list-sdks` `dotnet --list-runtimes`

Answer (score 11):

Run these commands:

```
sudo apt remove --purge dotnet-sdk-5.0.101
sudo apt remove --purge dotnet-runtime-5.0.101
```

Comment: not working for me

sudo dotnet --list-sdks
6.0.101 [/snap/dotnet-sdk/152/sdk]

sudo apt remove --purge dotnet-sdk-6.0.101
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package dotnet-sdk-6.0.101
E: Couldn't find any package by glob 'dotnet-sdk-6.0.101'

Comment: @madan Try with "major.minor", like `sudo apt purge dotnet-sdk-6.0`

Comment: thanks kol, i am afraid i do not currently have this issue so can't try the solution

Answer (score 7):

For the situation where `dotnet` has been installed using `snap`, you can do the following:

1. You need to list the names of the snap packages by going to the `/snap` directory. For example, on Ubuntu 21, my `dotnet` installations are shown in the following script.

   ```
   $ cd /snap
   $ ls
   ...
   dotnet-sdk
   dotnet-runtime-60
   ...
   ```
2. Then you can use the following commands to remove the snaps.

   ```
   sudo snap remove dotnet-sdk
   sudo snap remove dotnet-runtime-60
   ```

This was based on the answer for snap packages here:
[How to list files installed by a snap package?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/979233/how-to-list-files-installed-by-a-snap-package)

Answer (score 1):

All you have to do is just put the major version number, for example 3.1 or 5.0. You don't have to put any other minor version number/reference number just major version number will do.

For example for lets say your donet-sdk version is 3.1.416 then just right

```
sudo apt remove --purge dotnet-sdk-3.1
sudo apt remove --purge dotnet-runtime-3.1
```

Comment: FYI https://askubuntu.com/a/1388621/1210606 is the correct answer because this comment from am year ago https://askubuntu.com/questions/1305271/how-to-uninstall-dotnet-from-ubuntu-20-10-completely/1389528#comment2391729_1305274 showed it was a snap.

Comment: What a mess this is - been stuck for hours trying to install .net 6 & 7 - On my 5th full uninstall and reinstall - The FULL uninstall does not get rid of .NET so attempting a clean install not possible.

The microsoft instructions dont work - no surprise there, and I cant find any reliable instructions anywhere. None of the above commands remove everything. After using remove or purge, dotnet cmd is still showing.    The latest error is Segmentation Fault - corrupted memory.

Answer (score 0):

All you have to do is run this to remove all

```
sudo apt-get purge dotnet-sdk-*
sudo apt-get purge dotnet-runtime-*
```

or use version

```
sudo apt remove --purge dotnet-sdk-6.0
sudo apt remove --purge dotnet-runtime-6.0
```

Answer (score -1):

You can also use Synaptic to manage all installed versions.

```
sudo apt install synaptic
```