# How do I fix my broken .NET 6 installation?

Tags: dotnet

I have .NET 6 and .NET 7 on my Ubuntu system. When I try to execute a test in Rider it says dotnet 6 isn't installed. But it is. If I run `dotnet --list-runtimes` it shows only .NET 7.

Console output:

```
Reading state information... Done
aspnetcore-runtime-6.0 is already the newest version (6.0.110-0ubuntu1~22.04.1).
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 10 not upgraded.
aaronlord@system76-pc:~/Downloads$ dotnet --list-runtimes
Microsoft.AspNetCore.App 7.0.0 [/usr/share/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.AspNetCore.App]
Microsoft.NETCore.App 7.0.0 [/usr/share/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.NETCore.App]
aaronlord@system76-pc:~/Downloads$ dotnet --list-sdks
6.0.403 [/usr/share/dotnet/sdk]
7.0.100 [/usr/share/dotnet/sdk]
```

Comment: Idk for sure, but offhand I'd presume that `dotnet` binary is actually a symlink that points to either .NET 6 or .NET 7 installation. Similarly to `gcc` installation: you can have different versions of gcc, but the `gcc` binary will point to only one of them. You can change which version it's pointing to with `update-alternatives` command

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Step 1: Uninstall https://askubuntu.com/a/1386715/231561

Step 2: Set props in preferences.d https://stackoverflow.com/a/73899341/16454

Step 3: Install with some explicit values https://github.com/dotnet/sdk/issues/27082#issuecomment-1211181940

I used

```
sudo apt install aspnetcore-runtime-6.0=6.0.11-1 dotnet-apphost-pack-6.0=6.0.11-1 dotnet-host=6.0.11-1 dotnet-hostfxr-6.0=6.0.11-1 dotnet-runtime-6.0=6.0.11-1 dotnet-sdk-6.0=6.0.400-1 dotnet-targeting-pack-6.0=6.0.11-1
```